# SQL Server CE 4.0 SP1 central deployment

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I have created application which uses SQL Server CE 4.0 SP1. I tried using central deployment. So I added reference to `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` (of SQL Server CE 4.0 SP1 )using add reference in visual studio.

Then I tried running application in

1. On a windows XP PC having only .net 2.0 and SQL Server CE 4.0 SP1. But it didn't work and gave error like

   > System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
2. Then I tried on a PC with only .net 2.0 and SQL Server CE 4.0. It worked properly.

So how it does not work for SQL Server CE 4.0 SP1 even if I added `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` of SQL Server CE 4.0 SP1? What I am missing? Should i need to change anything in my code (.config) to target 4.0 SP1?

Comment: Bitness difference? Operating System x64 vs x32?

Comment: Set `Copy local = true` in referencing assembly properties

Comment: The installtion of SQL CE on the first PC is broken. Reinstall/repair. Make sure to reference assembly version 4.0.0.0 everywhere (and not 4.0.0.1). There is not api differnce between 4.0 and 4.0 SP1

Comment: @Steve operating system are same(32 bit)

Comment: @JesseJames if i set copy local=true to only System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll den i wil get error like "Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8854. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details." If I include all dll from SQL ce install folder(native components) then it works . but it will be private deployment.I have asked the same in question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548397/deploying-application-using-sql-ce-4-0-to-work-both-in-32-and-64-bit-pc and it worked.

Comment: @ErikEJ In first PC i have reinstalled sql ce 4.0 sp1 . in code i am reffering to 4.0.0.0 version itself. Still I am getting error. if in second PC sql ce 4.0 installed then only it works. In error case in both developer pc and the pc in which I tested I have installed same SQL CE 4.0(even same setup file) and both pc are Windows XP 32 bit.Target framework of project set to .net 2.0

Comment: You have the wrong installer, build 8854 is 4,0 SP1 CTP1, not 4,0 sp1 proper... http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/03/sql-server-compact-40-sp1-ctp1.html

Comment: Or you have the wrong runtime version installed on your dev pc

Comment: @ErikEJ Ok. Can't i use CTP1 ? does it has any problem? Then where I can download proper 4.0 SP1 not CTP1?

Comment: Ctp1 = beta, so should never be used in production, causing the problems you are facing! https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709

Comment: @ErikEJ I installed sql ce 4.0 sp1 from the link you mentioned in both developer pc and in tested pc. Still getting same error as mentioned in my question. i checked reinstalling/ repair also.

Comment: @ErikEJ I checked in another windows xp with only .net 2.0 sp2,3.5sp1 and SQL ce 4.0 SP1 ENU and it showed same error.Is there anything to do in project so that i can make the application to refer sql ce 4.0 sp1? The same error message comes even when application is run in pc not having SQL CE is installed. So the error message is like no sql ce installed.  Also pls check my previous comment.

Comment: Are you including System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll with yoir app? You should NOT do that...

Comment: @ErikEJ I have not included System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll. i have followed steps given in msdn and you articles. In some windows 7 and 8 pc it worked properly, but in that pc .net 4,4.5 etc are installed.I am out of ideas now, bcoz even after installing same exe in both developer and testing pc(both xp) its not working.

Comment: My articles are for private deployment, not central. Feel free to email me your proejct, and I will have a look and teel you what is wrong. Does the XP PCs run XP SP3 - that is required by SQL CE?

Comment: @ErikEJ Yes. it's XP SP3. I will email you soon.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Compact 4.0 requires .NET 3.5 SP1 or later. It will not run a machine with just .NET 2.0. See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876

Comment: I have checked in pc having only .net 2.0 and .net 3.5 sp1 and sql ce 4.0 sp1 and it didnt work(mentioned in my old comments).But my application has target framework 2.0. So now i will check after changing target framework to 3.5. Also central deployment worked with only .net 2.0 installed. So is central deployment works only with .net 2.0?!!

Comment: Again checked in pc having only .net 2.0 and .net 3.5 sp1 and got same error(application had target framework 3.5). Can u please tell me .net requirement for private deployment(in customer side). http://erikej.blogspot.in/2013/10/sql-server-compact-4-desktop-app-with.html  tell requirement on developer pc , but most important is what is required on customer side. For me sql ce 4.0 sp1 private deployment worked with only .net 2.0 in win xp sp3. So please clarify all these doubts. also chk my last comment

Comment: I checked in xp sp3 pc having .net 2 sp2, 3.0 sp2,3.5 sp1,4 client and extended and still getting same errors.   then in same pc unintslled sql ce 4.0 sp1 and installed sql ce 4.0 (without sp1) and it works fine.(as said in question). I am wondering why it works with sql ce 4.0 then(but from developer pc sql ce 4.0 sp1 dll added as reference)? So big question is how it works with 4.0 without sp1??